# pytest+celery: Test hangs

Tags: python, pytest, celery

I have a super simple celery task. During development, my broker for celery and pytest is sharing the same AWS SQS, and DynamoDB for results. My task was successful via CLI.

However, when running within pytest, my test would hang forever. When I force stop the test, it tells me it was stuck on the 'wait_for' function of `celery/backends/base.py:756`:

```
self = <celery.backends.dynamodb.DynamoDBBackend object at 0x1075354d0>, task_id = 'ac20975a-76db-495b-895f-f7905f2f6b81', timeout = None, interval = 0.5
no_ack = True, on_interval = <promise@0x10749af80>
```

*Note: code is simplified for stackoverflow.*

my env is apple m1pro macOS 13.0.1

python: python 3.11.0 (homebrew)

celery: 5.2.7

```py
# proj/tasks.py
from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


broker_transport_options = {
    'region': 'us-east-2',
    'predefined_queues': {
        'celery': {
            'url': 'https://sqs.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/../awesome_queue',
        }
    }
}

app = Celery(
    "awesome_queue",
    broker="sqs://",
    broker_transport_options=broker_transport_options,
    backend="dynamodb://@us-east-2/awesome_queue"
)

@app.task
def read_dynamodb( region: str, tablename: str) -> list:
    # Read from DynamoDB
    logger.info(f"Reading {region}/{tablename}")
    dynamodb_list = ["greetings"]
    logger.info(dynamodb_list)
    return region+tablename
```

My PyTest:

```py
# tests/conftest.py
from proj.tasks import broker_transport_options

@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def celery_config():
    return {
        "broker": "sqs://",
        "broker_transport_options": broker_transport_options,
        "backend": "dynamodb://@us-east-2/awesome_queue",
    }
```

```py
# tests/test_tasks.py
import pytest
from customer_shard_restore.tasks import app, read_dynamodb
from unittest.mock import patch


@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_app")
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("celery_session_worker")
class TestRestore:

    def test_read_dynamodb(self):
        result = read_dynamodb.apply_async("us-west-2", "blank")
        print(result.get())
```

Running CLI, I get the correct output:

```bash
# session 1
celery -A proj.tasks worker --loglevel=INFO
...
[2022-12-12 17:57:18,074: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task proj.tasks.read_dynamodb[829f0f0f-d177-4a4f-a045-7660f3b45ab6] succeeded in 0.9378940409806091s: 'somethingsomethingelse'
```

```py
# session 2
Python 3.11.0 (main, Oct 26 2022, 19:06:18) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from proj.tasks import read_dynamodb
>>> result = read_dynamodb.apply_async(("something", "somethingelse"))
>>> result.get()
'somethingsomethingelse'
>>> exit()
```